# Can you set a variable to a chain of echo commands? (.bat not .cmd)

Tags: batch-file

So with the if then command you can do this:

```
if %num1% == 1 (
 echo hello
 echo hi
 echo other
)
```

What I want to know is if you can do something similar such as:

```
set variable=(
echo hello
echo hi
echo other
)
echo %variable%
```

This is similar to calling a function in other languages except in batch, functions are structured differently.

(obviously my example doesn't make sense, but that's why I'm asking if there is another way of doing this?)

Comment: @Compo I apologize for not following the structure the community uses, it's on me for not investing more time into learning about it. I originally came here because it was a good location to ask questions about batch with a quick and helpful response, unlike other sites such as reddit or quora. I assumed I was doing everything correctly on here but I suppose I wasn't. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure your question will change now I've answered it, but here goes anyhow:

```batch-file
@Set "variable=@Echo hello&Echo hi&Echo other"
%variable%
@Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't invent this myself I also found this here in stackoverflow some time ago and copied it. I guess I searched for something like "store more than 1 line in a variable" or something. I'm unable to find the original thread right now but anyway it goes something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set LineBreak=^


:: The two empty lines above are required

set "Variable=Hello!LineBreak!Hi"
set "Variable=!Variable!!LineBreak!Other
echo !Variable!
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a variable can be used to execute a series of commands. In batch, this is often referred to as a macro.

Such macros can also be constructed to perform different actions depending on what argument is supplied when the variable is expanded

An example of a batch macro that accepts arguments much like a function and performs actions based on the validity of those arguments:

```bat
@Echo off & PUSHD "%TEMP%"
rem /* Macro Definitions */
(Set  \n=^^^
%= macro newline Do not modify =%
)
(Set LF=^


%= linefeed. Do not modify =%)
 If "!![" == "[" (
  Echo/%%COL%% macro must be defined prior to delayed expansion being enabled
  Goto :end
 )
 For /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (set "DEL=%%a")
rem /* %hCol% - Alternate color macro; escaped for use in COL macro. No error checking. Usage: (%hCol:?=HEXVALUE%Output String) */
 Set "hCol=For %%o in (1 2)Do if %%o==2 (^<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" ^> "!os!" ^& findstr /v /a:? /R "^$" "!os!" nul ^& del "!os!" ^> nul 2^>^&1 )Else Set os="
rem /* %TB%   - used with substitution within COL macro to format help output; not fit for general use, */
 Set "TB=^&^< nul Set /P "=.%DEL%!TAB!"^&"
rem /* %COL%  - main color output macro. Usage: (%COL%{[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]}{String to Print}) */
 Set COL=Set "_v=1"^&Set "Oline="^& For %%l in (1 2)Do if %%l==2 (%\n%
  If not "!Oline!" == "" (%\n%
   Set "_Str="%\n%
   For /F "tokens=1,2 Delims={}" %%G in ("!oline!")Do (%\n%
    Set "Hex=%%G"%\n%
    Set "_Str=%%~H"%\n%
   )%\n%
   Echo/!Hex!^|findstr /RX "[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]" ^> nul ^|^| (Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid - )%TB%(%hCol:?=06%Bad Hex value.)%TB%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%{!Hex!}{!_Str!})%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!)^&Set "_Str="^&Set "_v=0")%\n%
   If not "!_Str!" == "" (%\n%
    ^<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" ^> "!_Str!"%\n%
    findstr /v /a:!Hex! /R "^$" "!_Str!" nul %\n%
    del "!_Str!" ^> nul 2^>^&1%\n%
   )Else If not !_v! EQU 0 (%\n%
    Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid -)%TB%(%hCol:?=06%Arg 2 absent.)%TB%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%!Oline!)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=04%Input is required for output string.)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!)%\n%
   )%\n%
  )Else (Echo/^&(%hCol:?=04%Invalid -)%TB%(%hCol:?=06%No Args)%TB:TAB=!TAB!!TAB!%(%hCol:?=01%%%COL%%!Oline!)%TB:TAB=LF%(%hCol:?=02%!Usage!))%\n%
 )Else Set Oline=
 Set "usage=%%COL%%{[a-f0-9][a-f0-9]}{String to Print}"
 For /F eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in ('forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x09"') do Set "TAB=%%A"
rem /* removes escaping from macros to enable use outside of COL macro */
 Set "hCol=%hCol:^=%"
 Set "TB=%TB:^=%"
Rem /* prepare environment for macro expansion */
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 rem /* usage examples */
 (%COL%{02}{"green on black,"}) & (%COL%{10}{"black on blue"})
 Echo/
 (%COL%{04}{"red on black"}) & (%COL%{34}{" red on blue"})&(%COL%{40}{"black on red"})
 Echo/& %COL%{03}{Demonstration of error handling-}
rem /* error handling *
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 1 - No args
%COL%
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 2 - Missing 2nd Arg
%COL%{ff}
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=20%Example 3 - Invalid hex value for 1st Arg
%COL%{HF}{string}
 Echo/%TB:TAB=!LF! % %hCol:?=0d%Done
:end
POPD
Goto :Eof
```